# Android retrofit GET request

Tags: android, get, request, retrofit

Я новичок в разработке на android, прошу не судить строго.

Делаю GET запрос на сервер, который возвращает нам массив объектов. 
Сохраняю полученные данные я в видел List. Но из за строчки `newsList = api.getNews(jwtToken);` Приложение крашится, хотя я вроде бы все правильно  написал.

Хотелось бы узнать почему приложение крашится и как это исправить.
Код ниже

```
public class News extends ActionBarActivity {

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(Api.URL)
        .build();
Api api = restAdapter.create(Api.class);

TextView newsText;
SharedPreferences sPref;
String jwtToken;
List<news> newsList = new ArrayList<>();

public class news {

    String id, title, text, user, group, tags, comments, documents;

    public news(String id, String title, String user, String group, String tags, String comments, String documents){
        this.id=id;
        this.title=title;
        this.user=user;
        this.group=group;
        this.tags=tags;
        this.comments=comments;
        this.documents=documents;
    }
    public news (){}

    public String getId(){return id;}
    public String getTitle(){return title;}

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }
}

public interface Api{

    public static final String URL ="http://178.62.42.66/api/v1";
    public final String NEWS="/news/";

    @GET(NEWS)
    List<news> getNews(@Header("Authorization") String jwtToken);


}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news);

    newsText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextNew);

    sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedText = sPref.getString("token","");
    jwtToken = "JWT "+savedText;
    String url = "http://178.62.42.66/api/v1/news/";

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            newsList = api.getNews(jwtToken);
    String text = newsList.get(1).getTitle();


        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: приложите текст эксепшена

Comment: @hardsky я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Если вы запускаете в AndroidStudio, то краш должен вывеститсь в одно из вспомогательных окон студии.

Comment: @hardsky это то что нужно? http://pastebin.com/0zvcmg41

Comment: да, проверьте класс news, в который преобразуется json "retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 151 path $[0].documents", у вас в классе какое-то поле string, которое на самом деле должно быть коллекцией (или массивом).

Comment: @hardsky я исправил, теперь приложение не крашится, но оно не работает как надо. Если идти точкой останова, то в строчке newsList = api.getNews(jwtToken); она зависает(пытается выполнить, но не выполняет, пишет Waiting until last debugger command completes.